# Reason for difference in the date format with the same SQL Command?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time

When I am trying to run the below mentioned Query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(11), GETDATE(),106)
```

I get the result:

```
23 Jan 2015
```

Whereas, the query:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', IST), crea_date), 101)
FROM 
    Completed_Scrubs CS 
LEFT JOIN 
    TimeZonesTable TZT ON CS.States = TZT.State_US_CA 
WHERE 
    fiscal_week_num = 201549
```

And the query

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', IST), crea_date), 101), 105)
FROM 
    Completed_Scrubs CS 
LEFT JOIN 
    TimeZonesTable TZT ON CS.States = TZT.State_US_CA 
WHERE 
    fiscal_week_num = 201549
```

Return the same result:

```
(No column name)
12/31/2014
12/30/2014
12/19/2014
01/03/2015
01/06/2015
01/08/2015
01/01/2015
01/03/2015
01/07/2015
01/08/2015
```

Why? Is there a way to format the date in the above query as '23 Jan 2015'.

Comment: DATEDIFF and DATEADD aren't ANSI SQL. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh This looks like `SQL Server`.

Comment: well....yes. That's what the `106` format is doing, in the latter queries you are using the formats `101` and `105`

Comment: MSDN has an excellent page about the CONVERT() function and the different date formats it can return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CONVERT()` function accepts a format code (you have 101, 105, and 106 in your various queries) that tells SQL Server how to arrange the various pieces of a `DATETIME` field (for a full list of codes and the associated format, look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)).

Your queries are returning different results because you are telling them to by using different format codes.  Please review the linked documentation and choose the format code appropriate for your requirements - in this case, the `106` format in your first query.

Comment: This Worked!! :)

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(11), convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', IST), crea_date), 106) + right(convert(varchar(32),DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', IST), crea_date),100),8), 106)
FROM Completed_Scrubs CS LEFT JOIN TimeZonesTable TZT ON CS.States=TZT.State_US_CA WHERE fiscal_week_num=201549